# How to resolve Boost version conflict in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have a C++ application that uses a thirty part library that depends on Boost. When making the project I get this warning:

```
libboost_system.so.1.58.0, that is used in libthirdpaty.so  may conflict with libboost_system.so.1.61.0
```

In my cmake when I use `find_package(Boost)`, I get the following message:

```
-- Boost version: 1.61.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   system
--   filesystem
```

Question1: Is there way to remove the old boost library and make every one use the newer Boost library?

Question2: If not, how do I resolve this warning?

Comment: You could use a 1.58 version, too. Or you have to modify/update the third party library.

Comment: @usr1234567 Thanks for the answer. Do you know how I can remove a specific boost library (1.61 in this example) from my Ubuntu Linux system?

Comment: You don't have to. You can specify BOOST_DIR and only this will be used.